# How can a Partner User will able to see Reports based on Product/Pricebook

Tags: community, sharing, pricebook, partner-communities, owd

As mentioned by salesforce.com the Partner Users can only able to report on S/C-objects which are **Private** in Sharing Settings, then how can Partner Community User can see Products/Pricebook fields in Reports.

I am done many things, but not able to find that. Also there is no logic I got for not having access to Products/Pricebook for Partner Users.

Anyone have any idea, please share !

Thanks & Regards!
Chirag

Comment: While its admittedly a "hack", one option is to "mirror" your Products/Pricebook objects out to your Partner Community using triggers and custom objects to provide access to them for use by Partners.

Comment: This doesn't seems feasible, any other way ??

Comment: Its very feasible. I've done similar with Opportunity on Non Partner Community Portals. I don't know of another way. Perhaps someone else with jump in with one.