# How can I provide a partner user access to a report with order product fields?

Tags: reporting, orderitem

I have a report with Order and Order Product fields in it. The Partner Communities user has read permission to both Order and Order Product and no problem viewing them outside of reports (eg: in a detail page). The user can also access various other reports (all in the same folder). However, when a user tries to access the report, the message "Data Not Available" is displayed. Similarly, if user tries to create a new report based on the report type for that report then no order product fields are shown (but they are when an internal user accesses the same report type). I have changed the sharing for Order from "same as parent" to "private" and defined relevant sharing rules but still no go. Any suggestions?

I think that the problem may be rooted in the same issue described in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33265/how-can-a-partner-user-will-able-to-see-reports-based-on-product-pricebook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug of sorts or undocumented limitation when it comes to accessing Order Products and a few other objects related to Product from custom report types. In this case, the workaround is to use the standard report type "Orders with Products" and you get access to Order Product fields.

Answer (score 0):

The post you referenced would be out of date. Per [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=ja_6_2__7) at least read only access to all of the objects you mention, including `Products`, `Pricebooks`, `Orders` and `Opportunities`, is available to Partner Users provided you grant it to them.

There's a footnote on that page that may be worth noting to see if it applies to your org:

> Once orders are enabled, standard profiles automatically include all object permissions for orders, as well as read access for products and price books. If your external users are assigned to a standard profile and these object permissions aren’t appropriate for them, consider creating custom profiles that don’t include these object permissions.

Although it sounds like you may have already read it, you may want to look at [Received an "Insufficient Privileges" error message when trying to run a Report](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005189).

**Edit**

Here's an image of the schema that's involved taken from the SOAP API documentation at least a year or so ago, so it may be a bit out of date, but should still be fairly accurate. You can see the M-D relationships that exist which should propagate the record sharing and permissions that are necessary.

[image: Product2, Pricebook2, PricebookEntry, QLI, & Quote Schema]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am using a custom profile and the user definitely has access to orders and order products. I've been through each point on the page you referenced:

Comment: To continue from prev comment....
Report type is deployed; report folder definitely accessible (there are other reports in it that same user can access); User has read access to all fields on both Order, Order Product and Price Book. Double checked I am looking at right profile; Order sharing is private and I have sharing rules in place to grant the user access to the appropriate records.

Regarding the other post I referenced, I also can't include Product2 fields in reports for Communities users, hence why I thought it might be part of the same prob.

Comment: See my edited answer showing the schema that's involved for the objects.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, for access to Order Product, the only parent is Order. User has read access to Order therefore should have read access to Order Product. User also has read access to Pricebook2 and Product2, so they should have access to  PricebookEntry. Even if they didn't though, why would none of the fields for Order Product show up? Quote and QuoteItem are not master objects to any of the objects I'm trying to access so I haven't done anything about them. I might just go wild with permissions and see if most liberal settings helps...

Comment: Here's the full error I get. No mention of permissions, so perhaps that is not the problem here. I did try again after adding permissions for Quote just in case but made no diff. 

"Data Not Available   
The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page."